# CakePHP, Shell, PHP

Tags: php, shell, cakephp, command

I have an app in which I have a few cron jobs (these are outside cake), what I would like to do is the save cache using (Cakephp Cache Helper) by triggering through cakephp shell and create pdfs after the cron completes.

The pdf creation and cache creation logic is in the cake controller.

What I am trying to do is to call the cakephp app from shell (from the cron outside cakephp) and call a function from the controller and write the cache and pdf creation logic in it.

How can we call Controllers in Cake Shell?

Comment: You should ask yourself why your logic is in the controller and if you can move it to the model (Usually, this is the case). Then you can add $uses = array('ModelName') in your shell and call the logic like such: $this->ModelName->logicFunction($params);

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `requestAction` method within your shell:

```
$this->requestAction(Router::url('controller'=>'MyController', 'action'=>'myAction'));
```

It isn't well documented that you can do this but you should ask yourself whether you should move the logic elsewhere outside of the controller (e.g. into a library).

Comment: Hi Sam, The request action method doesn't work. It gives me errors.